# Phone number format

Tags: ipad, contacts

How can i stop Contacts from autoformatting phone numbers? It doesn't seem to matter which region I specify in settings it always registers phone numbers in a strange format: the first two numbers together then a space.  Why can't I just manually format ?

Comment: for USA numbers it should be 3 space 3 space and 4

Comment: And here in Spain it's 3-3-3.  So where does this 2-4-3 format com from?

Comment: On the Mac, you can specify formats for phone numbers matching any pattern; so, +1-###-###-#### will display any number that starts with 1 and has ten more digits, as above, regardless of the spacing/punctuation of the entered number.  This is in Address Book on 10.6; dunno about the later versions of OSX. But, even when the addresses are synced to the phone, this doesn't carry over.  And, the iCloud website has a "Automatically format phone numbers" option, which seems to affect only the iCloud website, and not the synced contacts.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a great question. I believe it used to be possible. The only way I know of now, is to use a custom field (like "Department"), change the label, and use it as if it were a phone number. It's hokey but it works.

Answer (score 1):

"Why can't I just manually format?"  You are not alone.  See this thread: [apple discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/message/19059111#19059111)

After some googling and experimentation, I have found what I believe are the intended methods of entering phone numbers are:

1. Type the number without a country code and OS X (and iOS) will format it with your computer's region/country settings.
2. Type the number with a country code (and a space) in front and the computer will format it based on the standard formatting for that country.

Some examples (I live in Australia):
0345678910 -> 03 4567 8910 (AU landline format)
0456789012 -> 0456 789 012 (AU mobile format)
+61 0345678910 -> +61 (0)3 4567 8910  (+61 is AU country code)
+61 345678910 -> +61 3 3567 8910  (I think this is *more* correct than previous line)
+1 2345678901 -> +1 (234) 567-8901   (USA)
+33 123456789 -> +33 1 23 45 67 89  (France)

No doubt, it isn't prefect.  But then some people don't know the officially correct formats for their own country.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aTelephone_numbers_by_country) has pages for numbering in every country.